# Archimedes property of real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Suppose $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $0 < x < 1 $ and $x \notin \{ \frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N} \} $. We want to show that there exists $n \geq 0$ such that

$$ \frac{1}{n+1} < x < \frac{1}{n} $$

MY attempt:

Given real number $x,y$, then there exists $n$ such that $nx >y $. This is the archimidean property. To obtain our result, we can put $y = z $, $x = 1$and $n = \frac{1}{N}$, then $\frac{1}{N} > z $. Similarly, we can put $n = N +1 $, $x = 1$ and $y = 1$ and $x = z$, then $(1+N)z > 1 \implies z > \frac{1}{N+1} $. Therefore, we have obtained $N$ such that 
$$ \frac{1}{N} > z > \frac{1}{N+1} $$.

this is what we wanted.

is this correct?

Comment: You proof fails from the start. It is *not* true that given $x,y$ real, there is an $n$ such that $xn>y$. Take $x=-2$ and $y=3$. Moreover, I think I know what you meant, but this is not the standard Archimedean Property: given $x \in \mathbb{R}$, there is an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x\leq n$. Furthermore, you obtain this result for what kind of $z$? It's not clear. At best you get it for $z=1$ or perhaps $y=z$? It's not clear in the proof. In either case, you have not shown it for any $z$ such that $0<z<1$.

Comment: Archimedean property of reals states that if $a > 0$ and $b$ is any real number then there is a positive integer $n$ such that $na > b$ (this is from Apostol's Mathematical Analysis). For your case choose $a = x$ and $b = 1$. This gives us an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $nx > 1$. By well ordering principle there is a least such positive integer $n$ and lets call it $N$. Thus we have $(N - 1)x < 1 < Nx$ and hence $\dfrac{1}{N} < x < \dfrac{1}{N - 1}$.

Comment: @mathematics2x2life, his statement of the Archimedean property is valid for positive real numbers and is more in line with the original statement by Archimedes.

Comment: @Spencer It is correct for positive reals, but this assumption is not made here. So it is false. And it may be in line with the original statement of Archimedes-I am unaware of its original statement. However, it is not the standard use of the phrase 'Archimedean Property' and is instead usually given as a corollary.

Comment: @mathematics2x2life, fair enough. I personally first learned the postulate as OP stated it in an real analysis course (with the appropriate caveats). The main reason I spoke up is that in the OP's question $0<x<1$ so the application of the property wasn't wrong though its statement was as you correctly pointed out. **Just for fun:** The original context of the postulate was in geometry when comparing the lengths of line segments. Archimedes realized that he needed this to be true in order for the method of exhaustion to be valid.

Comment: @Spencer When I took my first Modern Geometry course it was stated that the original statement of Archimedes was that involving the concept of length and that the idea was to be able to produce lengths larger than any given in a 'constructible' manner. How true this is, I am not sure but it does make some amount of sense in either case. I do prefer Mathematics taught through some historical context, alla Apostols works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like mathematics2x2life suggests the standard Archimedean property is that given any $x \in \Bbb R, \; \exists \ n_x \in \Bbb N$ such that $x \lt n_x$.

Through this we can find a natural number $n$ such that $\frac 1 n \lt x$. Therefore the set $A = \{n \in \Bbb N \ | \ \frac 1 n \lt x \}$ is non-empty. By the Well-Ordering principle this set has a least element say $m$.

Suppose  $x \ge \frac 1 {m-1} $. Then $x \gt \frac 1 {m-1} $ due to the stipulation that $x$ is not of the form $\frac 1 n $ for $n \in \Bbb N$ contradicting the fact that $m$ is the least element in $A$.

$\implies x \lt \frac 1 {m-1}$.

Here we have assumed that $m$ is not $1$. But $m =1 \implies x \gt 1$ leading to a contradiction..

Answer (score 1):

Your proof does not work. For one, it is not true that given $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, there is an $n$ such that $xn>y$. For example, take $x=-2$ and $y=3$. The rest of the proof is not clear. I am unsure if you are saying $z=y$ or $z=1$. But in either case you did not prove it for any $0<z<1$.

Finally, the Archimedean Property is that given any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, there is an $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x \leq n$. What you are referring to is true only for positive reals and is typically stated as a corollary to the Archimedean Property. In any case, I shall give a hint how to prove your statement.

**HINT.** Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $1<x$ and $x$ is not an integer. Show that there is an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n<x<n+1$ (use the Archimedean Property). Moreover, this integer $n$ is unique (not that uniqueness is needed). Then take the reciprocal in your inequality to obtain the result.